# A register of government decrees, authenticated with blockchain and public key cryptography

Tags: python, cryptography, blockchain

*The full repo is [here](https://github.com/tomhosker/chancery-b), but I'll post the most important extracts below.*

### Background

I'm trying to get the hang of **blockchain** and **public key cryptography**, so I thought it would be fun to create a program for drawing up and promulgating government decrees - the government in question being one that I've just made up.

The system is intended to work like this:

1. A government official in possession of the necessary passwords draws up a decree, stamps it with a digital stamp, and then adds it the register.
2. A private citizen then encounters decrees while going about his business:

   - If he encounters a decree in isolation, he can judge its authenticity using its stamp and the public key.
   - If he has access to the register, he can check that the government hasn't tried to hide an earlier decree by checking the chain of hashes.

### The Code

This is the code in which I make and verify my **stamps**, the certificates which authenticate decrees:

```py
### This code defines two classes: one of which produces a digital stamp for
### documents issued by the Chancellor of Cyprus, and the other of which
### verfies the same.

# Imports.
from cryptography.exceptions import InvalidSignature
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding, rsa
from pathlib import Path
import datetime, getpass, os

# Local constants.
path_to_digistamp = str(Path.home())+"/chancery-b/digistamp/"
path_to_private_key = path_to_digistamp+"stamp_private_key.pem"
path_to_public_key = path_to_digistamp+"stamp_public_key.pem"
public_exponent = 65537
key_size = 2048
encoding = "utf-8"

################
# MAIN CLASSES #
################

# A class which produces a string which testifies as to the authenticity of
# a given document.
class Stamp_Machine:
    def __init__(self, data):
        if os.path.exists(path_to_private_key) == False:
            raise Exception("No private key on disk.")
        self.private_key = load_private_key()
        self.data = data

    # Ronseal.
    def make_stamp(self):
        data_bytes = bytes(self.data, encoding)
        result_bytes = self.private_key.sign(
                           data_bytes,
                           padding.PSS(mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA256()),
                                       salt_length=padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH),
                           hashes.SHA256())
        result = result_bytes.hex()
        return result

# A class which allows the user to verify a stamp produced as above.
class Verifier:
    def __init__(self, stamp, data):
        if isinstance(stamp, str) == False:
            raise Exception("")
        self.stamp_str = stamp
        self.stamp_bytes = bytes.fromhex(stamp)
        self.public_key = load_public_key()
        self.data = data

    # Decide whether the stamp in question is authentic or not.
    def verify(self):
        data_bytes = bytes(self.data, encoding)
        try:
            self.public_key.verify(
                self.stamp_bytes,
                data_bytes,
                padding.PSS(mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA256()),
                            salt_length=padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH),
                hashes.SHA256())
        except InvalidSignature:
            return False
        else:
            return True

####################
# HELPER FUNCTIONS #
####################

# Get a password from the user, and convert it into bytes.
def get_bytes_password():
    password = getpass.getpass(prompt="Digistamp password: ")
    result = bytes(password, encoding)
    return result

# Get a NEW password from the user, and convert it into bytes.
def get_bytes_password_new():
    password = getpass.getpass(prompt="Digistamp password: ")
    password_ = getpass.getpass(prompt="Confirm password: ")
    if password != password_:
        raise Exception("Passwords do not match.")
    result = bytes(password, encoding)
    return result

# Generate a public key from a private key object.
def generate_public_key(private_key):
    public_key = private_key.public_key()
    pem = public_key.public_bytes(
              encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
              format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo)
    f = open(path_to_public_key, "wb")
    f.write(pem)
    f.close()

# Generate a new private and public key.
def generate_keys():
    if os.path.exists(path_to_private_key):
        raise Exception("Private key file already exists.")
    bpw = get_bytes_password_new()
    private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(public_exponent=public_exponent,
                                           key_size=key_size,
                                           backend=default_backend())
    pem = private_key.private_bytes(
              encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
              format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
              encryption_algorithm=
                  serialization.BestAvailableEncryption(bpw))
    f = open(path_to_private_key, "wb")
    f.write(pem)
    f.close()
    generate_public_key(private_key)

# Load the private key from its file.
def load_private_key():
    bpw = get_bytes_password()
    key_file = open(path_to_private_key, "rb")
    result = serialization.load_pem_private_key(key_file.read(),
                                                password=bpw,
                                                backend=default_backend())
    return result

# Load the public key from its file.
def load_public_key():
    key_file = open(path_to_public_key, "rb")
    result = serialization.load_pem_public_key(key_file.read(), 
                                               backend=default_backend())
    return result

###########
# TESTING #
###########

# Run the unit tests.
def test():
    stamp = Stamp_Machine("123").make_stamp()
    assert(Verifier(stamp, "123").verify())
    assert(Verifier(stamp, "abc").verify() == False)
    print("Tests passed!")

###################
# RUN AND WRAP UP #
###################

def run():
    test()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

This is the code in which a decree-in-the-making is **uploaded** to the register:

```
### This code defines a class, which uploads a record to the ledger.

# Imports.
import datetime, hashlib, os, sqlite3

# Local imports.
from digistamp.digistamp import Stamp_Machine
import ordinance_inputs

# Constants.
encoding = "utf-8"

##############
# MAIN CLASS #
##############

# The class in question.
class Uploader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = None
        self.c = None
        self.block = Block_of_Ledger()

    # Ronseal.
    def make_connection(self):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect("ledger.db")
        self.connection.row_factory = dict_factory
        self.c = self.connection.cursor()

    # Ronseal.
    def close_connection(self):
        self.connection.close()

    # Add the ordinal and the previous block's hash to the block.
    def add_ordinal_and_prev(self):
        self.make_connection()
        query = "SELECT * FROM Block ORDER BY ordinal DESC;"
        self.c.execute(query)
        result = self.c.fetchone()
        self.close_connection()
        if result is None:
            self.block.set_ordinal(1)
            self.block.set_prev("genesis")
        else:
            self.block.set_ordinal(result["ordinal"]+1)
            self.block.set_prev(result["hash"])

    # Add the hash to the present block.
    def add_hash(self):
        m = hashlib.sha256()
        m.update(bytes(self.block.ordinal))
        m.update(bytes(self.block.ordinance_type, encoding))
        m.update(bytes(self.block.latex, encoding))
        m.update(bytes(self.block.year))
        m.update(bytes(self.block.month))
        m.update(bytes(self.block.day))
        if self.block.annexe:
            m.update(self.block.annexe)
        m.update(bytes(self.block.prev, encoding))
        self.block.set_the_hash(m.hexdigest())

    # Add a new block to the legder.
    def add_new_block(self):
        new_block_tuple = (self.block.ordinal, self.block.ordinance_type,
                           self.block.latex, self.block.year,
                           self.block.month, self.block.day,
                           self.block.stamp, self.block.annexe,
                           self.block.prev, self.block.the_hash)
        query = ("INSERT INTO Block (ordinal, ordinanceType, latex, year, "+
                 "                   month, day, stamp, annexe, prev, "+
                 "                   hash) "+
                 "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);")
        self.make_connection()
        self.c.execute(query, new_block_tuple)
        self.connection.commit()
        self.close_connection()

    # Construct a new block and add it to the chain.
    def upload(self):
        self.add_ordinal_and_prev()
        self.add_hash()
        self.add_new_block()

################################
# HELPER CLASSES AND FUNCTIONS #
################################

# A class to hold the properties of a block of the ledger.
class Block_of_Ledger:
    def __init__(self):
        dt = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.ordinal = None
        self.ordinance_type = ordinance_inputs.ordinance_type
        self.latex = ordinance_inputs.latex
        self.year = dt.year
        self.month = dt.month
        self.day = dt.day
        self.annexe = annexe_to_bytes()
        self.prev = None
        self.the_hash = None
        self.stamp = None

    # Assign a value to the "ordinal" field of this object.
    def set_ordinal(self, ordinal):
        self.ordinal = ordinal

    # Assign a value to the "prev" field of this object.
    def set_prev(self, prev):
        self.prev = prev

    # Assign a value to the "the_hash" field of this object.
    def set_the_hash(self, the_hash):
        self.the_hash = the_hash
        self.stamp = Stamp_Machine(self.the_hash).make_stamp()

# A function which allows queries to return dictionaries, rather than the
# default tuples.
def dict_factory(cursor, row):
    d = {}
    for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
        d[col[0]] = row[idx]
    return d

# Convert the annexe folder to a zip, load the bytes thereof into memory,
# and then delete the zip.
def annexe_to_bytes():
    if len(os.listdir("annexe/")) == 0:
        return None
    os.system("zip -r annexe.zip annexe/")
    f = open("annexe.zip", "rb")
    result = f.read()
    f.close()
    os.system("rm annexe.zip")
    return result

###################
# RUN AND WRAP UP #
###################

def run():
    Uploader().upload()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

And this is the code in which decrees are **extracted** from the register and put into something more human-readable, i.e. a PDF:

```
### This code defines a class which takes a given record in the ledger and
### converts it into a directory.

# Imports.
from uploader import dict_factory
import os, sqlite3, sys

# Local imports.
from digistamp.digistamp import Verifier

# Constants.
month_names = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug",
               "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

##############
# MAIN CLASS #
##############

# The class in question.
class Extractor:
    def __init__(self, ordinal):
        self.ordinal = ordinal
        self.block = self.fetch_block()
        self.main_tex = self.make_main_tex()

    # Fetch the block matching this object's ordinal from the ledger.
    def fetch_block(self):
        connection = sqlite3.connect("ledger.db")
        connection.row_factory = dict_factory
        c = connection.cursor()
        query = "SELECT * FROM Block WHERE ordinal = ?;"
        c.execute(query, (self.ordinal,))
        result = c.fetchone()
        connection.close()
        if result is None:
            raise Exception("No block with ordinal "+str(self.ordinal)+
                            " in the ledger.")
        return result

    # Get the base for main.tex, given the type of the Ordinance.
    def get_base(self):
        if self.block["ordinanceType"] == "Decleration":
            path_to_base = "latexery/base_decleration.tex"
        elif self.block["ordinanceType"] == "Order":
            path_to_base = "latexery/base_order.tex"
        else:
            raise Exception("Invalid ordinanceType: "+
                            self.block["ordinanceType"])
        f = open(path_to_base, "r")
        result = f.read()
        f.close()
        return result

    # Make the code for main.tex, which will then be used build our PDF.
    def make_main_tex(self):
        day_str = str(self.block["day"])
        if len(day_str) == 0:
            day_str = "0"+day_str
        packed_ordinal = str(self.ordinal)
        while len(packed_ordinal) < 3:
            packed_ordinal = "0"+packed_ordinal
        month_str = month_names[self.block["month"]-1]
        result = self.get_base()
        result = result.replace("#BODY", self.block["latex"])
        result = result.replace("#DAY_STR", day_str)
        result = result.replace("#MONTH_STR", month_str)
        result = result.replace("#YEAR", str(self.block["year"]))
        result = result.replace("#PACKED_ORDINAL", packed_ordinal)
        result = result.replace("#DIGISTAMP", self.block["stamp"])
        return result

    # Check that the block isn't a forgery.
    def authenticate(self):
        self.compare_hashes()
        self.verify_stamp()

    # Compare the "prev" field of this block with the hash of the previous.
    def compare_hashes(self):
        if self.ordinal == 1:
            if self.block["prev"] != "genesis":
                raise Exception("Block with ordinal=1 should be the "+
                                "genesis block.")
            else:
                return
        prev_ordinal = self.ordinal-1
        connection = sqlite3.connect("ledger.db")
        c = connection.cursor()
        query = "SELECT hash FROM Block WHERE ordinal = ?;"
        c.execute(query, (prev_ordinal,))
        extract = c.fetchone()
        connection.close()
        prev_hash = extract["0"]
        if prev_hash != self.block["prev"]:
            raise Exception("Block with ordinal="+str(self.ordinal)+" is "+
                            "not authentic: \"prev\" does not match "+
                            "previous \"hash\".")

    # Check that this block's stamp is in order.
    def verify_stamp(self):
        v = Verifier(self.block["stamp"], self.block["hash"])
        if v.verify() == False:
            raise Exception("Block with ordinal="+str(self.ordinal)+" is "+
                            "not authentic: \"prev\" does not match "+
                            "previous \"hash\".")

    # Ronseal.
    def write_main_tex(self):
        f = open("latexery/main.tex", "w")
        f.write(self.main_tex)
        f.close()

    # Compile the PDF.
    def compile_main_tex(self):
        script = ("cd latexery/\n"+
                  "pdflatex main.tex")
        os.system(script)

    # Create the directory, and copy the PDF into it.
    def create_and_copy(self):
        script1 = ("cd extracts/\n"+
                   "mkdir "+str(self.ordinal)+"/")
        script2 = "cp latexery/main.pdf extracts/"+str(self.ordinal)+"/"
        if os.path.isdir("extracts/"+str(self.ordinal)+"/"):
            os.system("rm -r extracts/"+str(self.ordinal)+"/")
        os.system(script1)
        os.system(script2)

    # Write annexe to a file in the directory.
    def write_annexe_zip(self):
        if self.block["annexe"] is None:
            return
        f = open("extracts/"+str(self.ordinal)+"/annexe.zip", "wb")
        f.write(self.block["annexe"])
        f.close()

    # Do the thing.
    def extract(self):
        self.authenticate()
        self.write_main_tex()
        self.compile_main_tex()
        self.create_and_copy()
        self.write_annexe_zip()

    # Ronseal.
    def zip_and_delete(self):
        script = ("cd extracts/\n"+
                  "zip -r ordinance_"+str(self.ordinal)+".zip "+
                      str(self.ordinal)+"/\n"+
                  "rm -r "+str(self.ordinal)+"/")
        if os.path.exists("extracts/ordinance_"+str(self.ordinal)+".zip"):
            os.system("rm extracts/ordinance_"+str(self.ordinal)+".zip")
        os.system(script)

###########
# TESTING #
###########

# Run a demonstration.
def demo():
    e = Extractor(1)
    e.extract()
    #e.zip_and_delete()

###################
# RUN AND WRAP UP #
###################

def run():
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        e = Extractor(int(sys.argv[1]))
        e.extract()
    else:
        print("Please run me with exactly one argument, the number of the "+
              "Ordinance you wish to extract.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

### What I'd Like to Know

- **Am I using blockchain and public key cryptography in a sane fashion?** Or have I misunderstood some of the fundamental concepts involved?
- **Are there any glaring security issues?** Is there any obvious exploit in which someone could start manufacturing convincing forgeries?
- How's my Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neat question! I'm afraid I ran out of steam before reaching anything too crypto-ish, though. There's a lot of Python to unpack here.

The repeated comment "Ronseal." is [cute if you know the reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Does_exactly_what_it_says_on_the_tin) but I guess you know it doesn't help the reader; I'd rather save a line of screen real estate.

Re Python style, I recommend running your code through `flake8` and fixing everything it complains about (with the possible exception of line-length warnings). It'll rightly complain about commented-out code like

```
#e.zip_and_delete()
```

---

```
def write_annexe_zip(self):
    if self.block["annexe"] is None:
        return
    f = open("extracts/"+str(self.ordinal)+"/annexe.zip", "wb")
    f.write(self.block["annexe"])
    f.close()
```

Either this is another in-joke that I *don't* get, or you misspelled "annex." (You certainly misspelled "declaration" and "ledger" at least once each.) I also looked for anywhere you might have explained what an annex[e] actually *is* in this context, without success.

If `f.write` throws an exception, then `f.close()` won't happen and you'll have leaked a file handle. It's always best to use RAII constructions for this kind of thing: i.e.,

```
def write_annexe_zip(self):
    if self.block["annexe"] is not None:
        with open("extracts/%d/annexe.zip" % self.ordinal, "wb") as f:
            f.write(self.block["annexe"])
```

Looks like you haven't learned `printf` format strings yet. It's a really good investment in your career! Consider:

```
    day_str = str(self.block["day"])
    if len(day_str) == 0:    ## I'm guessing this was a typo?!
        day_str = "0"+day_str
    packed_ordinal = str(self.ordinal)
    while len(packed_ordinal) < 3:
        packed_ordinal = "0"+packed_ordinal
```

versus what you could have written:

```
    day_str = "%02d" % self.block["day"]
    packed_ordinal = "%03d" % self.ordinal
```

Anything you can do to eliminate *mutation* (repeated overwriting) of your variables is a good thing for maintainability. In this case it's also shorter and clearer.

---

```
    script1 = ("cd extracts/\n"+
               "mkdir "+str(self.ordinal)+"/")
```

I'm surprised that `os.system()` allows you to pass multiple commands separated by newlines. However, here it would be clearer to do it in a single command. There's no reason for you to change working directories before creating the `extracts/foo` directory.

```
def create_and_copy(self):
    mypath = "extracts/%d" % self.ordinal
    if os.path.isdir(mypath):
        os.system("rm -r %s" % mypath)
    os.system("mkdir -p %s" % mypath)
    os.system("cp latexery/main.pdf %s" % mypath)
```

---

```
class Stamp_Machine:
    def __init__(self, data):
        if os.path.exists(path_to_private_key) == False:
            raise Exception("No private key on disk.")
        self.private_key = load_private_key()
        self.data = data
```

- Why is `path_to_private_key` not a *function parameter* to `load_private_key`?
- Why is `load_private_key` a free function? Shouldn't it be a private implementation detail (i.e., a member) of the `Stamp_Machine` class?
- The construction `if f() == False` would be better expressed as `if not f()`.
- Are you at all concerned that someone might remove the file in between the time you check for its existence and the time you read it? (This is a "TOCTTOU" vulnerability.)
- Are you at all concerned that someone might replace the file with another file, such as a private key under their personal control?

---

```
    if isinstance(stamp, str) == False:
        raise Exception("")
    self.stamp_str = stamp
```

This should at *least* raise `RuntimeError("expected a string")`. And in reality, you shouldn't manually raise an exception at all; any operation that requires a string will eventually raise `TypeError`, which is plenty self-descriptive, and if no such operation ever takes place, then maybe you didn't need to raise an exception in the first place.

You never use the member variable `self.stamp_str`, so you shouldn't be creating it.

---

You repeatedly pass `backend=default_backend()` to crypto functions. That's redundant; by definition, the backend that will be used by default *is* the default backend.

---

```
password = getpass.getpass(prompt="Digistamp password: ")
password_ = getpass.getpass(prompt="Confirm password: ")
if password != password_:
    raise Exception("Passwords do not match.")
```

This seems to be conflating two different kinds of "error handling." Superficially, this function's job seems to be to interact with the *user*, present a prompt to the *user*, and wait for the *user* to type in their new password. But then when the user makes a typo, you don't ask the *user* to fix their typo; you raise a programming exception indicating an unexpected failure to be handled by *code in your calling routine*. What's the calling routine supposed to do about it?

This should just be a loop:

```
while True:
    password = getpass.getpass(prompt="Digistamp password: ")
    password_ = getpass.getpass(prompt="Confirm password: ")
    if password == password_:
        break
    print("Your two inputs did not match. Please try again.")
```

---

```
# Add the hash to the present block.
def add_hash(self):
```

This function operates only on `self.block`. Shouldn't it be a member function of `Block_of_Ledger` instead?

Incidentally, Python style would be CamelCase, e.g. `BlockOfLedger` or simply `LedgerBlock`.

---

It is absolutely insane that creating a `Block_of_Ledger` object in Python — i.e., the single line

```
foo = Block_of_Ledger()
```

— causes the program to irretrievably delete files from disk. That just shouldn't happen. You should write a conspicuously named function that deletes files, and then use its result as a *parameter* to the constructor. E.g.:

```
annex = collect_annex_files(delete_from_disk=True)
foo = Block_of_Ledger(annex)
```

Similarly, `dt = datetime.datetime.now()` should be a parameter to the constructor. Everything you write should be unit-testable, and that means no hard dependencies on external realities like "time" or "disk" or "network" or "database." Look up [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and/or watch [this excellent talk on unit-testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5senBJUkPc).

Comment: Thank you for such a thoughtful and useful review. Inevitably, there are a few suggestions which I've decided **not** to carry out - although I've carried out all the others - and which I detail below...

Comment: 1. The spelling ***annexe*** is British English, like *axe* and *programme* (although not even I use the latter). It pains me every time Gmail tries to nudge me into using an American spelling, and this is my way of fighting back!

Comment: 2. I'm aware of `printf`-ery. (Would you believe that C was my first language?) And I like what you've done here. However, I'm going to keep things as they are because: (A) in Python, I'll always prefer something *verbose but clear* over something *terse*, and (B) I still have PTSD from my days as a C programmer!

Comment: 3. So `backend=default_backend()` is redundant? Ah, that'll be why it throws an exception when I remove that snippet!

Comment: 4. Yes, the constructor of `Block_of_Ledger` calls a function which deletes a file, but that same function **creates** the file to be deleted only 4 lines up. I really don't find that insane - either absolutely or relatively.

Comment: Thank you again. I've push the revised code to GitHub ([here](https://github.com/tomhosker/chancery-b)). I really want to get someone to look at security side of things. Now that the bulk of the lower-level issues have at least been discussed, what's the best way of achieving this? Should I ask a fresh question?

Comment: "Should I ask a fresh question?" — Probably yes. CodeReview etiquette forbids updating _this_ question in place; so your options are "ask a fresh question re the updated code" or "go somewhere besides CodeReview" (but I have no better options to suggest).
Re 4.: Oops, I misread `zip -r annexe.zip annexe/ ... rm annexe.zip` as `rm -r annexe.zip annexe/`. That's less insane. It would still be good to use the `tempfile` module here, or even better, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463770/python-in-memory-zip-library to avoid touching the filesystem at all.